# notepad++ REGEX how to find matched string and keep it (delete all surrounding text)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to use regex function to find the following string AAA and delete everything else (except the ending part of this string)

Example:

```
eenqowtnorynwny55w4oynw AAABBB ewtenoqtn3oyn AAACCC 4et3o4ny3ny AAADDD 3to3n4yon45yo
wetn3o4tn3o5yn AAAZZZ wn3otn3on AAANNN
```

expected outpout

```
AAABBB
AAACCC
AAADDD
AAAZZZ
AAANNN
```

Comment: find value can be any length - AAACCC or AAACCCCCCCCCDDE

Comment: `(?s)(AAA\w*)|.` => `(?{1}$1\n:)`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked!!! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `[^A-Z]*`  Replace with: `\n` can work with match-case ticked